# How do you add datetime to a logfile name?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

When I create my logfile,  I want the name to contain the datetime.

In Python you can get the current datetime as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 3, 21, 35, 9, 559000)
```

The str version is

```
>>> str(datetime.now())
'2012-02-03 21:35:22.247000'
```

Not a very nice str to append to the logfile name!  I would like my logfile to be something like:

```
mylogfile_21_35_03_02_2012.log
```

Is there something Python can do to make this easy? I am creating the log file as:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler("mylogfile" + datetimecomp + ".log")
```

Comment: this was probably easily googled.

Comment: The title makes me laugh, luckily your question body is good or I would have no idea what "anyold anytime" means :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have filename in year, month, day etc order so that sorted directory listings weren't a pseudo-random jumble?

Comment: On Stackoverflow, you're supposed to do research before posting a question.

That being said, you ought to use:

`datetime.now().strftime('mylogfile_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')`

... for more reasonable file ordering.

Comment: Harsh.  This question is much simpler and was voted up to 56. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python  I also googled and was also wondering was there a smmarter way thant gettting a datetime and formatting it.

Comment: Yes there is: use a `TimedRotatingFileHandler`!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need [**`datetime.strftime()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), this allows you to format the timestamp using all of the directives of [C's `strftime()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strftime/). In your specific case:

```
>>> datetime.now().strftime('mylogfile_%H_%M_%d_%m_%Y.log')
'mylogfile_08_48_04_02_2012.log'
```

Comment: I prefer an ISO-style date-time format as it makes sorting much easier.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

Comment: @Sabrina I'm not sure that I understand your comment. Are you saying that you're getting this error on executing the line of code from my 7-year-old answer? Did you do something like `import datetime` rather than `from datetime import datetime` as in the question I was answering?

Comment: If you are getting an error like --AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'-- Use --from datetime import datetime-- instead of --import datetime-- and then you can continue using logFileName = datetime.now().strftime('ALL_%H_%M_%d--%m_%Y.log')

Answer (score 46):

You could also use a [**`TimedRotatingFileHandler`**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) that will handle the date and the rollover every day (or whenever you want) for you.

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
fh = TimedRotatingFileHandler('mylogfile',  when='midnight')
```

By default the format will be depending on the rollover interval:

> The system will save old log files by appending extensions to the filename. The extensions are date-and-time based, using the strftime format `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` or a leading portion thereof, depending on the rollover interval.

But you can modify that as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338566/1132524), by doing something like:

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
fh = TimedRotatingFileHandler('mylogfile',  when='midnight')
fh.suffix = '%Y_%m_%d.log'
```

Comment: +1. Why reinvent the wheel when Python's already done such a great job!

Comment: I am not seeing any option through which we can generate a new file with timestamp each time program is run. Is there any way?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Have a look at the datetime API, in particular `strftime`.

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another Solution using format():

```
#generates a date for a generic filename
import datetime
date_raw = datetime.datetime.now()
date_processed = "{}-{}-{}_{}-{}-{}".format(date_raw.year, date_raw.month, 
                  date_raw.day, date_raw.hour, date_raw.minute, date_raw.second)
#example value: date_processed = 2020-1-7_17-17-48
```

I used this in my own project
edit: as I found out about f(ormatted)-strings, this would be another solution:

```
date_processed = f"{date_raw.year}-{date_raw.month}-{date_raw.day}_{date_raw.hour}-{date_raw.minute}-{date_raw.second}"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use datetime.now() to get current timestamp. Here is my code that I am using to create log file with timestamp -

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
LOG_FILENAME = datetime.now().strftime('D:/log/logfile_%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y.log')
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
      logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)    
logging.info('Forecastiong Job Started...')
logging.debug('abc method started...')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import strftime

fh = logging.FileHandler(strftime("mylogfile_%H_%M_%m_%d_%Y.log"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To print `hour`, `minutes`, `day`, `month` and `year`, use the following statement

from `datetime` import `datetime`

```
print datetime.now().strftime("%H_%M_%d_%m_%Y")
```