# Adding datestamp to the log file's file name in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, logging, time

I have a program which is set to run for a long period of time and I keep a log file to keep track of the events. However, the size of the log file is getting bigger as time goes by.

I would like to keep a log file everyday instead of just one log file for everything.

This is my current code:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='myfile.log',level=logging.INFO)
```

I want to set a date for the log file such that, it will become myfile_DDMMYYYY.log and creates another log file everyday with the different date.

Any idea if it is possible to be done ?

Comment: you can concatenate filename with `str(datetime.date.today())` and use `time.sleep` to write the log every other day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want datetime in logfile name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135936/want-datetime-in-logfile-name)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> filename = now.strftime('myfile_%d%m%Y.log')
>>> filename
'myfile_09032017.log'
```

the easiest way to get a new log every day would be to simply exit after 24 hours, and have Upstart or inittab restart it for you with `respawn`.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do something like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('abcd')
logger.setLevel( logging.INFO )
fH     = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(
            'folderName', 
            dt.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S')+'_value.log'))
```