# Including date in the log file name & creating log files of certain size while keeping last 3 log files in python with `logging.config.dictConfig()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am setting up python logger using config. I want log file to contain date (and possibly time). I also want for that date, each log file to be of only particular size and to keep only 3 such old log files.

For example, I will like to get log files of following form:

```
mylog-2018-09-11.log
mylog-2018-09-11.log.1
mylog-2018-09-11.log.2
mylog-2018-09-11.log.3
```

I tried RotatingFileHandler using config of following form as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#a-more-elaborate-multiprocessing-example):

```
config = {
    #...
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'mplog.log',
            'mode': 'w',
            'formatter': 'detailed',
            'maxBytes': 10000,
            'backupCount': 3
        },
    },
    #...
}
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

and it produces log files as follows:

```
mylog.log
mylog.log.1
mylog.log.2
mylog.log.3
```

But I am unable to understand, how can I get date in the log file names. Is it possible to do it with configs and with some handler say `RotatingFileHandler` or `TimeRotatingFileHandler`? Or say can I somehow set the log file name to contain date after `dictConfig()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows a `RotatingFileHandler` which rotates files based on size rather than date. You need to use `TimedRotatingFileHandler` as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler). You can configure it in the same way as you have done `RotatingFileHandler`.

**Update:** If you want to restrict both by date *and* size, you will need to use a handler subclass which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Are you sure? `maxBytes` is present in the arguments of [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler), but is not present in [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler)

Comment: When I said "in the same way", I meant "in the same _general_ way", not "_exactly_ the same way".

Comment: Sorry not still able understand. What do you mean by "handler subclass"? I have to write custom one? Any link?

Comment: [...continued] also does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45447081/1317018) answer suggest that its not possible?

Comment: Sorry, no link (I don't think it's a common requirement). Yes, you have to write custom code, and it _is_ possible if you know what you want to achieve.